# Manipulating the record data fetched using <force:recordData>

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using `<force:recordData>` to display my record details in lightning component. Here I have a scenario where I need to split an api field[based on a key] and to display the values in 3 fields.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.record}"  
                      targetFields="{!v.CIRRecord}"
                      mode="EDIT"    
                      />
```

Since the record details are fetched directly I am not able to manipulate the record data. Can anyone help in this?

Comment: You will have to create a custom component

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to get your idea. Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split the field out and display it in 3 separate places, as well as making updates to that field, you will need to utilise the JS Controller or Helper to do this, you will then need to utilise a Server-Side/Apex Controller to handle the updates to the record data.

Comment: As I mentioned I am using <force:recordData>. So,how to call other methods??

Comment: You should take a look at Salesforce's trailhead section on this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_data_service/units/lightning_data_service_manipulate_records

Comment: we created our component after going through the trailhead page https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_data_service/units/lightning_data_service_manipulate_records

Answer (score 0):

Other than the attributes/events exopsed and documented at [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordData.htm), you cannot use the out of the box component to achieve what you want. You will have to "Code" aka, create your own lightning component to have control over how and what you want displayed in your form.

The components are little black boxes that can't really be tampered with.

Comment: do you mean to remove <force:recordData> and to use some other way to fetch and display the record details?